# What do you call someone that acts on possibilities?

Tags: psychology, personality

I'm making a video game, I can not think of what you call a person that acts on possibilities, like what mindset do you call them or what type of person are they?

Example: Hi traveller, I might help you or I might not?

Likewise as if they join your party and may act like they're good but kill you.
Or they may say the right way to go or not and lead you to your doom.
But its in a way of a gamble, there is no way to tell if they will be good or not. What would you call a person who acts like this?

Comment: Personally, I'd call them bloody unreliable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

risk-tolerant
risk-taker
deliberate
strategic
flexible
adaptive
methodical
bold
unpredictable

Comment: It would improve the answer if you justified each of these word selections.